# Magento onepage checkout: Continue button not working in magento 1.7..

Tags: magento-1.7

magento 1.7 
onepage checkout stuck after choosing a payment method. I have found a few solutions but none work. I don't really want to mess with the .js files unless it's a proper fix. seemed to work fine a few days back. No extensions installed since then.

Weinwerk Klimascout: [Click here to view the site.](http://www.weinwerk-klimascout.de) 
 Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

So I encountered the same problem (also with 1.7.0.2). It sneaked in after I added a number of custom modules.

After a day or so of trying just about everything I could think of, I found a rather simple solution: I had accidentally deleted some of the directories from the "skin\frontend\base\default" directory

In particular, check to make sure there are no issues with the files in the "default\js" directory. The "opcheckout.js" file controls the advance process in onepage checkout.

I ended up reinstalling all the subdirectories "skin\frontend \base\default" and this did the trick.

(Just to confirm, once fixed, rename the file to opcheckout.js.bak and the continue button will revert to no- working state).

I’m sure there are many other possible reasons for this bug. jquery.noconflict() and billing.phtml and are worth a look. For others who might be new to magento, the debugging steps here are a lifesaver.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store